# spark-submit error - "Local jar does not exists, skipping"

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

Spark: 3.3.0 (spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3)

I am trying to run spark-submit using jar files, but I receive "jar does not exist" from DependencyUtils, even if the JAR is in place. As a consequence the mainClass is not found.

Command:
`./spark-submit --class <package-name>.<class-name> <project-path>.jar`

The error I am getting:

```
Error: Failed to load class <package-name>.Application.
INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Comment: Can you show the full error, in which the `jar does not exist` is included?

Comment: Show us your class definition and how you're packaging it... Have you tried testing your installation with the Spark examples jar?